# Importing Java class X from outside the project into Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

So I'm trying to use a GrovePi open library in my project to use the LEDs on my GrovePi. Currently the specific class that lets me access the LEDs is stored at `import com.dexterind.grovepi.sensors.Led;` 
Now that I try to import the specific class I get an error where Eclipse doesn't recognize `com.dexterind`. I believe it's because it's not in my project and it's scope isn't to find packages outside my source folders and the jars in my build path. I know I have to change some config file in the project folder but I can't seem to find it. 
Also, getting a Jar doesn't seem to be an option as I only want that one class. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: does that package exist??, I mean do you have the right version of the jar lib??

Comment: "Add Class Folder" or "Add External Class Folder" in the fancy manual: http://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-properties-build-path.htm

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ I don't have a jar lib for that package, and I know this is a very dumb question, but how do I get it? The package is in a git repo at https://github.com/DexterInd/GrovePi/blob/351d0f655ae4935baf8c603b9af8b9cf3e6a4b48/Software/Java/src/com/dexterind/grovepi/sensors/Led.java

Comment: @RC. I was looking into that before posting here and the problem is that I would need to download the folder with the source code from that package, is there any way to keep my project clean and not bring in source code from other projects and importing from outside?

Comment: then add the git project as a REssourceFolder in eclipse.

Comment: you can avoid downloading by using maven

Comment: maven will resolve the dependencies issue for you

Comment: you will need to define the pom file for the project

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse have the option to **add external class folder into your buildpath**, but using this option **you could have some issues with dependencies** that  the class would have. I think the best solution is import the jar.

[image]